# Reverse for 'delete_reply' with arguments '(7, '')' not found

Tags: python, django

I am a new for Django and need some help.
I want to make a 'delete' function regarding comments, but when I clicked the deletion button, I got the error

> Reverse for 'delete_reply' with arguments '(7, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['boards/(?P<board_pk>[0-9]+)/reply/(?P<reply_pk>[0-9]+)/delete/\Z']

I guess that there is no pk for the **reply_pk**, so I tried to give the pk into the url. However, I couldn't get the answer what I want. I spend lots of time to find solutions on google and here, but all wonderful answers couldn't help me to fix it.

I attached my code here and please help me

**model.py**

```
class ReplyBoard(core_models.TimeStampedModel):
    reply = models.TextField(default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(user_models.User, related_name = "reply", on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    board = models.ForeignKey("Board", related_name = "reply", on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
```

**view.py**

```
class Board_detail(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = kwargs.get("pk")    
        try:
            form = forms.ReplyForm()
            board = board_models.Board.objects.get(pk=pk)
            
            return render(self.request, "boards/board_detail.html", {"board": board, "form": form})
        except board_models.Board.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404()




def create_reply(request, board_pk):
    
    form = forms.ReplyForm(request.POST)
    if request.method =="POST":
        board = board_models.Board.objects.get(pk=board_pk)
       
        if form.is_valid():
            reply = form.save()
            reply.board = board
            reply.user = request.user
            reply.save()

            messages.success(request, "creted the comment.")
            return redirect(reverse("boards:board_detail", kwargs={"pk": board.pk}))

@login_required()
def delete_reply(request, board_pk, reply_pk):
    
    try:
        reply = board_models.ReplyBoard.objects.get(pk=reply_pk)
        
        if request.user != reply.user.pk:
            messages.error(request, "cannot delete the comment..")
        else:
            reply.delete()
    except board_models.ReplyBoard.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    
    return redirect(reverse("boards:board_detail", kwargs={"pk": board_pk}))
```

**urls.py**

```
path("", views.BoardView.as_view(), name="ask_view"), 
path("<int:pk>/", views.Board_detail.as_view(), name="board_detail"),
path("<int:pk>/edit/", views.EditBoardView.as_view(), name="board_edit"),
path("<int:board_pk>/delete/", views.Delete_Board, name="board_delete"),
path("create-board/", views.CreateBoardView.as_view(), name="create-board"),
path("reply/<int:board_pk>/", views.create_reply, name="create_reply"),
path("<int:board_pk>/reply/<int:reply_pk>/delete/", views.delete_reply, name="delete_reply")
```

**html**

```
<a href="{% url 'boards:delete_reply' board.pk reply.pk %}" class="btn-link">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this way

```
(r'^reply/(?P<board_pk>\d+)(?:/(?P<reply_pk>\d+))?',views.delete_reply, name="delete_reply"),
```

Comment: you help me to solve the problem! thank you, but I got another problem. when I clicked the button, I got HTTP ERROR 405, I added full code for urls.py